# Андроид текущая дата и спустя 7 дней

Tags: java, android

Нужно чтобы после нажатия кнопки, алерт диалог не появлялся 7 дней. Насколько я понимаю, необходимо использовать calendar class. Примерно в таком формате. 
`Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,7);`
Но как передать значения от текущей даты, до следующей, чтобы алерт принял preference, а счетчик дат обнулился например.

Comment: Как то Вы сильно закрутили вопрос. Добавьте код который Вы используете для решения этой задачи. И напишите более детально какая стоит у Вас задача и что из нее не получается сделать. Например: юзеру нужно показать то-то с такой-то периодичностью.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

При каждом показе сохранять текущую дату в преференсах, когда захочется снова показать окно - считать и сравнить. Если прошло меньше 7 дней (или 168 часов или 10080 минут или 604800 секунд, смотря как требует задача), то не показывать.